# LicheePi_Zero with LCD config

Tags: linux, kernel, config, lcd

I have the lichee pi zero board and LCD tft 800x480 SH500J04Z. I download the linux kernel 5.2.y and do the next selection on menuconfig:

Device Drivers --->Staging drivers --->Support for small TFT LCD display modules --->

the LCD i have has the HX8264/HX8664 driver and I can't find those between the options.
Now I have the linux working through uart0 but the LCD I can only see the pinguin logo and nothing more. I found this link [enter link description here](https://www.cnblogs.com/linux-37ge/p/12688735.html)

on the LCD I cn only see the u-boot and the pinguin logo on init, and then nothing more. I guess this is a driver issue but don't know what else to check to make the LCD work. I was thinking that maybe i need to modified the dtsi or dts file, but found that those are correct. Linux is working but the lcd is not. Any help will be appreciated!!

Gastón